# How to have an action bar like macos on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, operating-system, customization, windows-11

I can't find a way to customize my Windows to have the app toolbar (File - Edit - Windows - Help - ...) detached from the app and fixed on top of the screen like macos.

It has been a while since I started looking for a way to customize my Windows, especially to move the Action Bar or Tool Bar, I don't really know how it's called, in order to have a look similar to mac os.

[image]